# Random Range returns two numbers instead of one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So Im trying to make a card game i want to make move 1 random card to the position when a trigger collides with another card but when i do that the script move 2 cards instead of one

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Det.GetComponent<Isacard>().Iscard == true)
    {

        int sandom = Random.Range(1,6);
        Debug.Log(sandom);
        if (sandom == 1 && cS != null)
        {
            cS.transform.position = new Vector3(-.33f, 4.53f, 0);
        }
        else
        {
                       if (sandom == 1 && cS != null)
        {
            cS.transform.position = new Vector3(-.33f, 4.53f, 0);
          }
 }
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have run same if statement twice.

```
if (sandom == 1 && cS != null)
    {
        cS.transform.position = new Vector3(-.33f, 4.53f, 0);
    }
    else
    {
          //return; or do whatever needs to be done         
    {
        
      }
```